# Is this a pug template bug or my misunderstanding of the grammar?

Tags: pug

I have the following code:

```
- var a = 5;
- var b = 3;
script
  if (a === 5)
    if (b === 2)
    .
      var x = true;
  include script.js
```

I want to include the script.js file when `a == 5` and if `b === 2`, I want to insert a new line `var x = true` above, inside the  tag.

However, when I use the code, the `x = true` is always inserted.

[image]

You can verify it here:

https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to indent the `.` and `var x` lines one more level so that they're within the second conditional:

```
- var a = 5;
- var b = 3;
script
  if (a === 5)
    if (b === 2)
      .
        var x = true;
  include script.js
```

If you want `x` to always be declared and be either true or false based on your conditions, another approach would be something like this:

```
- var a = 5
- var b = 3
script
  | var x = #{a === 5 && b === 2}
  include script.js
```

This will make `x` true if the Pug variables `a` and `b` are `5` and `2` respectively, and `false` if not.